# PyQt4 unable to call function of main Gui class from QThread class

Tags: python, pyqt4, qthread

Following is the sample code structure I am intending to implementing a larger time consuming operation. For doing larger operation, I have used QThread and updating progressbar (from main class) using the emited signal. All works fine un till large time consuming operation is completed. However, I run in to problem when I call a function from main GUI class. Here is the code structure I am trying (read the comments):-

```
import time
from scripts.gui import Ui_Dialog
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import QtCore

class AppGui(QtGui.QDialog, Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self)
    # Main code here.
    # This GUI pops up for user input and opens a main GUI.

    def main_function(self):
        # Doing some main coding here.

        self.work_thread = WorkThread()
        self.work_thread.update.connect(self.ui.progressBar.setValue)
        self.work_thread.start()

        # I wanted to continue more coding here after the thread is finished. But self.work_thread.wait() is blocking main gui.
        # Therefore, I moved the continuation code to different function --> sub_function()

    def sub_function(self):

        # Do the remaining code left over from the main_function()


class WorkThread(QtCore.QThread):


    update = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)

    def __del__(self):
        self.wait()

    def run(self):

        self.thread = GenericThread(scripts.function, arg1, arg2)  # This "scripts.function()" function does long process.
        self.thread.start()

        while self.thread.isRunning():
            # Do some long process.
            time.sleep(1)
            self.update.emit(signal)

        print "Distro extraction completed..."


        if self.thread.isFinished():
            self.main_class = AppGui()
            self.main_class.sub_function()  # <-- Problematic call to main AppGui function.

        if self.isFinished():

            return


class GenericThread(QtCore.QThread):

    def __init__(self, function, *args, **kwargs):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)
        self.function = function
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def __del__(self):
        self.wait()

    def run(self):
        self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
        return
```

This is what I got after running.

> What I believe is that I am wrongly calling function of main AppGui() from WorkThread() class.

```
QPixmap: It is not safe to use pixmaps outside the GUI thread
Larger operation is complete...
QObject::installEventFilter(): Cannot filter events for objects in a different thread.
[xcb] Unknown request in queue while dequeuing
[xcb] Most likely this is a multi-threaded client and XInitThreads has not been called
[xcb] Aborting, sorry about that.
python2.7: ../../src/xcb_io.c:179: dequeue_pending_request: Assertion `!xcb_xlib_unknown_req_in_deq' failed.
```

Any help to solve this issue is appreciated.

Comment: The general rule is never to do GUI work in more than one thread. In the case of a worker thread you can get around this limitation by sending a signal from the worker thread to the GUI thread requesting it to update the progress. This may be done e.g. by `QCoreApplication::postEvent()`

Comment: I have done exactly done what you have said. I am getting the signal from WorkerThread to update main Gui progressbar. The problem only come when I try to execute sub_function() of AppGui() class from other class (WorkerThread() class). I need to experiment with `QCoreApplication::postEvent()` though.

Comment: Another user having exact problem like me. But no answer/ code yet to be posted here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11695649/how-do-i-tell-my-main-gui-to-wait-on-a-worker-thread?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that worker thread emit a signal, this signal could not directly bind to an UI slot, but you need to bind it to a general slot, then you call the UI slot to upgrade. As I don't have all your code, so Ｉ write a similar file like this, it works fine

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import time


class WorkerThread(QThread):
    updateSignal = pyqtSignal(int)

    def run(self):
        count = 0
        while True:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            self.updateSignal.emit(count)
            count += 1


class ProgressBar(QProgressBar):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ProgressBar, self).__init__(parent)
        self.worker = WorkerThread()
        self.worker.updateSignal.connect(self.updateProgress) # here should bind to a general slot

    def startWorker(self):
        self.worker.start()

    def updateProgress(self, progress):
        self.setValue(progress)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    p = ProgressBar()
    p.startWorker()
    p.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: I got your point. Updating progress bar is not a problem in my case. How do I continue my next code after progress is completed? How can I tell main class to wait for large operation to complete? Where do my large time consuming operation fit in to above example. Your example is working without an issue.

Comment: In my view,  you should not make the UI thread wait for the long time consume thread to be finished, something like thread.join(), this should never be directly called from UI thread, because this will most likely make your UI freezing. Instead, you could use signal-slot to notify the UI thread updating, if you need after longtime thread finished, you code could continue, you can emit a signal again after got a finished signal from progress bar

Comment: Thank you for the input. I have restructured my code based on your suggestion. Accepting your answer.